# What's the difference between Directory.Delete(folder) and Directory.Delete(folder, false)?

Tags: c#, directory

What's the difference between the two code segments below?

```
Directory.Delete(folder)
```

and

```
Directory.Delete(folder, false)
```

?

I mean, both of them will delete the specific folder if it's empty; 
otherwise, they will raise exception, am I right? Or is there anything I miss? Thanks!

Comment: Copy Directory.Delete > Paste in Google > Click on 1st result > https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Just press `F12` to Get Details about all parameters ..  not neet to post here

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov SO wants us to justify the down-vote.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is mentioned in the **[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete(v=vs.110).aspx)** itself and it says

```cs
Delete(String)
```

**Deletes an empty directory from a specified path.**

```cs
Delete(String, Boolean)
```

**Deletes the specified directory and, if indicated, any subdirectories and files in the directory.**

and when you pass `true` as the `boolean` variable then it removes directories, subdirectories, and files in path.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
  Delete(String)
```

> Deletes an empty directory from a specified path.

```
Delete(String, Boolean)
```

> Deletes the specified directory and, if indicated, any subdirectories
>   and files in the directory.
>
> The path parameter may specify relative or absolute path information.
>   Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current
>   working directory. To obtain the current working directory, see
>   GetCurrentDirectory.
>
> Trailing spaces are removed from the end of the path parameter before
>   deleting the directory.

[More information](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxeahc5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The path parameter is not case-sensitive.
>   If the recursive parameter is true, the user must have write
>   permission for the current directory as well as for all
>   subdirectories.
>
> The behavior of this method differs slightly when deleting a directory
>   that contains a reparse point, such as a symbolic link or a mount
>   point. If the reparse point is a directory, such as a mount point, it
>   is unmounted and the mount point is deleted. This method does not
>   recurse through the reparse point. If the reparse point is a symbolic
>   link to a file, the reparse point is deleted and not the target of the
>   symbolic link.
>
> In some cases, if you have the specified directory open in File
>   Explorer, the Delete method may not be able to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

> Directory.Delete(folder, boolean)

boolean decides if we want to delete any subdirectories and files in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

[Directory.Delete Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62t64db3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> This method behaves identically to Delete(String, Boolean) with false specified for the second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

`Delete (String, Boolean)` basically delete files and folders recursively if boolean is set to true and if set to false it only delete the empty directory otherwise it will raise an exception.

while `Delete(String)` only deletes the empty directory and if folder is not empty it will raise an exception.

The directory must have required permissions to perform the delete in both cases.